# how to handle the mysql error in nodejs?if the result is an empty array?

Tags: mysql, node.js, error-handling, ejs

i have a nodejs code given below. The sql query works perfect when i gave a valid data, if the input is not available in sql it will return a null result (result []).How do i render this to another page if the result is an empty array?

```
app.post('/verify',urlencodedParser,async function(req,res){///////////// verify form
    var reg1 = req.body.regno;
    console.log("reg");
    console.log(reg1);

    sql ="select * from json where id="+db.escape(reg1);
    db.query(sql,async(err,resulter)=>{
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log("my result:",resulter);

        console.log(resulter[0].name);
    jname = resulter[0].name;
    var contents = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path1 + "/public/issued_json/"+jname, 'utf8'));
    console.log(contents);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(contents.employee[0]));
```

Comment: `if (resulter.length === 0) { // some action }` ?

Comment: its worked..thanks broo @1556089774